# How to get informed when: Sum of a column, in a empty subset

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to find a way to detect, when in a sum, the subset is empty.
The code bellow explains what I mean.

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,2,2,2), c(0,2,1,3,0,1))

# Subset of the rows, in which the first column is 3
# ( Notice that there is any 3 in the first column )
# Sum the second column of this subset
sum(df[ df[,1]==3 ,2 ] )
```

Is there any function that can inform me if the subset is empty or returns me *NA*, in this sum? Currently, the *sum* function is returning 0, although the subset is empty. It doesn't seems right to me, as a sum of 0 elements is Non Existent, rather then 0.

Comment: Try with `if(any(df[,1]==3)) sum(df[df[,1]==3, 2]) else NA`  Instead of creating two `==`, use `i1 <- df[,1] ==3; if(any(i1)) sum(df[[2]][i1]) else NA`

Comment: the function that is missing is any, then. Thank you. However, could you explain me what does `df[[2]][i1]` works? Why is it better then `i1[,2]`?

Comment: Naming your columns would make things a lot easier.

Comment: Here, `df[[2]]` is extracting the second column and then subset the rows based on the logical index.  It could improve the performance slightly as we are working with vector instead of subsetting row/column in a data.frame (not tested)